# "this" in JAVA, more explanation

Tags: java, this

Suppose that I have a code like this

```
public void init(){
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

Based on JAVA docs,

Within a method or constructor, this refers to the current object, the object whose method or constructor is being called ...

based on the code, I can take a conclusion that  "this" refers to the object on which `init()` method is called not `addMouseListener()` or `addMouseMotionListener()`

is it true?

Answer (score 11):

`this` refers to the current object, the one that has the init method, yes, and the one that you're adding your MouseListener and MouseMotionListener to. It also ***is*** the MouseListener and MouseMotionListener. You may be asking this poor class to do too much.

I suggest that you don't have your GUI or applet classes also implement listener interfaces since this can make your code difficult to debug and extend.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. When you do

```
someFunction();
```

it's the same as doing

```
this.someFunction();
```

So in your example, you have some Object that both TAKES listeners and IS a listener. Essentially you're telling the Object to listen to itself. You're doing

```
this.addMouseListener(this);
```

The initial `this` is implied when the method isn't qualified.

The same goes for `static` methods too. If you have a `static void someStatic() { }`, any time you call `someStatic();` it's the same as going `MyClass.someStatic();`

Answer (score 2):

That is true. The keyword "this" refers to the instance of object on which init() is called eg the object is set as MouseListener and MouseMotionListener

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword is a reference to the current class instance, but when you pass it into, say, addMouseListener, you are passing the implemented Interface reference, in this case would be [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html).